# Método retornando nome do objeto no entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Eu tenho o seguinte método:

```
internal ArquivoVersao GetArquivoVersao(string arquivoVersaoGuid)
    {
        using (var ctx = new TestEntities())
        {
            var versao = (from ver in ctx.ARQUIVO_VERSAO
                          where ver.ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID == arquivoVersaoGuid
                          select new ArquivoVersao()
                          {
                              ARQUIVO_GUID = ver.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                              ARQUIVO = ver.ARQUIVO,
                              USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID = ver.USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID,
                              TAMANHO = ver.TAMANHO,
                              DATAHORA = ver.DATAHORA,
                              ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = ver.ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID
                          }).FirstOrDefault();
            return versao;
        }
    }
```

eu quero mostrar o resultado, ao chamar esse metodo ele mostra o objeto, queria mostrar um valor na tela.
Eu mandei um  .ToString()  mas não vai.

Comment: Como você tenta exibir este valor na tela?

Comment: Response.write("Valor:"+dal.GetArquivoVersao.ToString());

Comment: ou armazenar o metodo em uma string, tanto faz

Comment: Você está tentando da um .ToString() no Objeto... tenta fazer assim ARQUIVOdal.GetArquivoVersao.ARQUIVO.ToString()

Comment: desse jeito ele me retornou o tipo dele, System.Byte[]

Comment: Qual campo você quer exibir? basta colocar no lugar de arquivo, como por exemplo. ARQUIVOdal.GetArquivoVersao.DATAHORA.ToString()

Comment: FUncionou, obrigado, se quiser criar resposta, eu do um joinha. Valeu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está tentando da um .ToString() no Objeto.

Tenta fazer assim

```
ARQUIVOdal.GetArquivoVersao.NOME_DA_PROPRIEDADE_QUE_QUER_EXIBIR.ToString();
```

Comment: FUncionou, obrigado

Comment: Se eu tiver um metodo q retorna uma lista do entity, como ficaria? aparece no metodo.ToList, mas nao soube como mostrar

Comment: Creio que você terá que fazer um FOREACH(objeto in lista)

Comment: Beleza, valeu...